# Python regex: how to replace string except if another string exist on the same line?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, mediawiki, regex-negation, pywikibot

I am fixing the spell of some articles with[`replace.py`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/replace.py)by replacing *"choeur"* by *"chœur"*.
There are also file links in the mediawiki syntax :

```
[[Fichier:Menditte (Pyr-Atl, Fr) choeur de l'église.JpG|thumb|Chœur de l'église]]
```

Editing that kind of thing will broke the link. I can't use `[]` because there's also the link description :

```
[[Fichier:JeronimosRoyalTombs.Jpg|thumb|right|Tombeaux de [[Jean III de Portugal]] (à gauche) et de [[Catherine de Castille]] (à droite) dans la choeur de l'église]]
```

In that case, the spell should be fixed.
So I need to not do the edit if there is`.jpg`on the same line and after *"choeur"*.

My problem is I couldn't find the way to handle boolean expressions inside [python regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead `(?!...)` *(not followed by)*:

pattern:

```
(?i)\b(ch)oe(urs?\b)(?!.*\.jpg\b)
```

replacement:

```
$1œ$2
```

About word boundaries:

Word boundaries are used to delimite letters for `\bchoeurs?\b` or `\.jpg\b`, and would do the job in most cases. However, keep in mind that the word boundaries will not work with this string: `__choeur__`. If needed, word boundaries can be replaced with lookarounds, example:

`(?:(?<=_)|\b)choeurs?(?=_|\b)`

Comment: It don't work. `# python replace.py -namespace:0 -recursive -summary:"test" -xml:../frwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml -regex "(?i)\b(ch)oe(urs?\b)(?![^][|]*\.jpg[][|])" "chœur"`
`bash: ![^][: event not found`

Comment: @user2284570: Try to use double backslashes `\\b` `\\.`

Comment: It can't work if you don't use `.*` before `jpg`. It suppose `jpg` immediately follow the string, which is the case in my example, but most of the time, it is not.

Comment: @user2284570: `choeur [[Fichier:choeur aaaa.jpg|......]]`: in this example, must the first "choeur" be replaced?

Comment: @user2284570: Ok, If I understand well there is no limit until the end of the line.